# What is the recommended hardware for developing a SMS gateway?

Tags: programming-languages, gsm, sms-gateway

Our company is planning to develop a small SMS gateway, an internal system for sending and receiving SMS notifications. The project is assigned to me. I look online for a GSM module but it gives me a lot of confusion on what hardware and programming language to use. I just want to ask what would be your best recommendation to help me get started with this project? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SIM modem, where you would insert SIM cards that are able to send/receive SMS messages. You can read out the messages received and send content through a custom program or gnokii for example.

Far more easy is using a [SMS Gateway](https://www.budgetsms.net), like Budgetsms.net. They have a HTTP API you can implement, basically as simple as calling an URL.
You can also get delivery updates pushed to your server.